# Spark Streaming saveastextfile operation, what are part0000 files

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

When I run saveAsTextFiles("prefix","postfix"); for JavaDStreams, I have found that multiple part files are created.

I would like to understand what each part file signifies?

The files have the following naming, /part0000, part0001, part0002

Code to create a line based RDD flatmap that I used to output these files

```
JavaDStream<String> words = lines.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
  @Override
  public Iterable<String> call(String x) {
    return Lists.newArrayList(NEWSPACE.split(x));
  }
});
```

My assumption was that this is creating a DStream of RDD's with each RDD= 1 line, and hence should create 1 part file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An DStream is a collection of RDDs over time. Each RDD is composed of partitions of data distributed across the cluster of Spark workers.

[image]

In this illustration, each colored line represents a stream of data. When it's bounded in an rdd, it's a partition of the RDD. The RDD is composed by the data collected at each time interval, represented here by the blue box.

DStream.saveAsTextFile will create a file for the RDD created at interval (bluc box) each part-file corresponds to the piece of the colored line bounded by such RDD (colored line within blue blox).

In a distributed file system, like hdfs, the fs will abstract out the partitioning, presenting you with a single logical file, or 1 file per RDD.

When you use the local file system, those part-files will the explicit as you are seeing.

(*) Credits for the image: Spark presentation at Devoxx 2014 by Andy Petrella and Gerard Maas (me)

Comment: I am sorry can you explain further? What does the folder correspond to, and what do the part files correspond to? Are you saying that each part file corresponds to the output of a single rdd in a dstream interval?

Comment: I think I now understand it better, can you also explain the difference between the time duration of a DStream and an RDD? I.e. when we set up streaming context, does it set up the duration for the redbox/ or the RDD? How is the size(time) of the bluebox(RDD), and DStream batch (redbox) set?

Comment: There's an RDD produced each interval defined by 'batchDuration' (blue box).  The DStream lasts for as long as your streaming program runs (the red line  .... could be hours, days, years,...)

Comment: What do the part files mean, if the data is being run on a single local node? (which is my case).. i.e. I have only one local node, shouldn't I have only a single part file generated then? I see several even in my local instance..

Comment: In local mode you still have several cores processing tasks in parallel. Each partition of the rdd will become 1 part file. Want only 1 file? Do rdd.coalesce(1). Be warned that this will prevent any parallel processing.